# DISTINCT for two out of three columns

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I want the DISTINCT/FirstValue when a unique account_id value for one Person_id and one ah_person_id, doesn't matter which one, but also sometimes there Person_ID with a different Ah_person_id as well. Example Table

```
Person   AH_PERSON   ACCOUNT_ID
A         1           22
B         2           23
B         2           24 
C         3           25
C         4           26
```

What I want back
Expected Results

```
Person   AH_PERSON   ACCOUNT_ID
A         1           22
B         2           23
C         3           25
C         4           26
```

I tried using Group by and DISTINCT but I don't get the results I want, Can anyone have an example?
Thank You

```
SELECT DISTINCT person_id,
(SELECT ah_person_id
  FROM w_accnt
WHERE id = My_Table.account_id) AH_PERSON ,
account_id 
FROM My_Table
```

Comment: Distinct will take in consideration all columns in the select.so the uniqueness is not just for one column but for the combination of all three.  So Distinct is not what you want, you need to use Group and or some other logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd group by the `person_id` and `ah_person_id`, and take the minimal `account_id`:

```sql
SELECT   person_id, ah_person_id, MIN(account_id)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY person_id, ah_person_id
```

Comment: what if one of the columns is a subquery?

Comment: @Branderson20 . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  If one of the columns is  subquery, you can use a CTE or subquery and then use this logic.  If that doesn't do what you want, ask a *new* question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sql ROW_NUMBER function to solve that

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try this script? it can be the solution for you question

```
;WITH cte AS(
SELECT
*,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AH_PERSON ORDER BY ACCOUNT_ID ASC) AS OrdererAccounts
from
#MyTable
)

SELECT
    Person, AH_PERSON, ACCOUNT_ID
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    OrdererAccounts = 1
ORDER BY
    PERSON
```